# Issue which showing the image

Tags: angularjs

**What am I trying?**

On button clicking showing the progress bar and hiding the button that was clicked.

**Problem**

Button is not hiding and image is not showing. I inspected the element and I can confirm that the image is given correct url.

**My AngularJs Html is below**

```
<form ng-submit="doLogin();" novalidate name='loginForm'>
    <input type="text" name="EmailAddress" ng-model="credentials.EmailAddress" required/>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-show="{{RegisterShow}}">
        Login
    </button>
    <img ng-src="{{imgProcessingPath}}" ng-show="{{imgProcessingShow}}">
</form>
```

**Controller is below**

```
myApp.controller('LoginController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

        $scope.imgProcessingPath = appUrl + "Images/ajax-loader.gif";
        $scope.imgProcessingShow = false;
        $scope.RegisterShow = true;

        angular.extend($scope, {
            doLogin: function() {
                $scope.imgProcessingShow = true;
                $scope.RegisterShow = false;

                var data = {
                    "EmailAddress": $scope.credentials.EmailAddress
                };
                userModel.doLogin(data).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.imgProcessingShow = false;
                    $scope.RegisterShow = true;
                },function(response) {
                    $scope.imgProcessingShow = false;
                    $scope.RegisterShow = true;
                });
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing the curly braces for ng-show in html file!

```
ng-show="RegisterShow"
```

alternatively you can also use

```
ng-if="RegisterShow"
```

Comment: Is there any way to eliminate the duplicate code that is present in `then` and fail callback to hide image and show button again?

Comment: You can keep them in a function and call the function! from `then` and `fail` callback blocks.

Comment: Is there any on complete callback?

Comment: We can remove the duplicate code that may run after success or fail callback. Is there any?

Comment: not any as of it i know right now! its interesting. ill let you know if i find any! :)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-show` should not have an expression, it acts like `model` variable,

Change it as,

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-show="RegisterShow">
```

also

```
<img ng-src="{{imgProcessingPath}}" ng-show="imgProcessingShow">
```

Comment: Is there any way to eliminate the duplicate code that is present in then and fail callback to hide image and show button again?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer as I don't have the rep to comment.

Remove the brackets inside ng-show.

```
<img ng-src="{{imgProcessingPath}}" ng-show="imgProcessingShow">
```

Comment: Is there any way to eliminate the duplicate code that is present in then and fail callback to hide image and show button again?